# Jquery menucool slider want to change effect

Tags: jquery, slider

I am using jquery menucool slider, how do I remove "slider purchase reminder" or if I want to change slider effect...

Comment: Here you go - it explains in their licence agreement.  You have to buy it.  http://www.menucool.com/auth/license-agreement

Comment: Your Website or JSFiddle containing code??

Comment: @PratikJoshi Please read my comment before you consider spending any time on this.

Comment: I will remove this ,If the Slider JS is not Encrypted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change your effect, change the values in js-image-slider.js

```
effect: "6,15,1,2,11,12,13,15,16,5,7",
```

to your effect, like

```
effect: "13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13",
```